# Finding the CDF of a function of a random variable, given the CDF of a random variable

Tags: probability, solution-verification, cumulative-distribution-functions

I'm given the following problem:

> Suppose that $X$ is a continuous random variable, with CDF ($F_X$)
> given by:
>
> \begin{cases} 
>       0 & x < 0\\
>       1 - e^{-x} & x \geq 0    \end{cases}
>
> Find the CDF of $(X-10)^2$.

---

*Attempted solution.*

Let $Y = (X - 10)^2$. As $X$ is a random variable, $Y$ must also be a random variable.

Let $F_Y$ be the CDF of $Y$. By definition:

$F_Y = P(Y \leq y) = P((X - 10)^2 \leq y ) = P(10 - \sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y} + 10)$

It can be shown that *(this is given in the class text)*:

$= F_X(\sqrt{y} + 10) - \lim_{x\to 10 - \sqrt{y}} F_X)\;\;\;$

But this
$= F_X(10 + \sqrt{y}) - F_X(10 - \sqrt{y})$ since $F_X$ is continuous.

---

Now, we find $F_X(10+\sqrt{y})$ and $F_X(10 - \sqrt{Y})$...

$F_X(10 + \sqrt{y})= \{\;1 - e^{-(10 + \sqrt{y})} \;\;\;|\;\;\; 10 \leq 10 + \sqrt{y}\;\}$

$F_X(10 - \sqrt{y})=$
\begin{cases} 
     0 & x < 0\\
     1 - e^{-(10 - \sqrt{y})} & 0 \leq 10 + \sqrt{y} < 10
   \end{cases}

---

Unfortunately, I'm not sure where to go from here (it doesn't seem to me that the difference can be taken?). Further, I'm not entirely confident in what I have thus far.

**Is this a valid approach, and what's the next step?**

Comment: I think you have a typo or two, or at least some formatting issues? -- namely, the part that was given in the class text. Also, your expression for $F_X(10 - \sqrt{y})$ has a plus instead of a minus. Nevertheless, $P(Y\le y) = F_X(10 + \sqrt{y}) - F_X(10 - \sqrt{y})$, as (I think) you said. However, this simplifies a bit when $y$ gets big enough. Hint: Consider the support of $X$.

Comment: @dmk Thanks for the input! I've corrected the latter typo. The excerpt from the text is given verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

Using the support of $X$,

$F_X(10 − \sqrt y) = 
\begin{cases} 
     0 & y \gt 100\\
     1 - e^{-(10 - \sqrt{y})} & 0 \leq y \leq 100
   \end{cases}
$

Also, $F_X(10+\sqrt y) = 1 - e^{-(10 + \sqrt{y})},  y \geq 0$

As you rightly said,  $F_Y(y) = F_X(10 + \sqrt{y}) - F_X(10 - \sqrt{y})$. So,

$F_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 
0 & y \lt 0 \\
     e^{-(10 - \sqrt{y})} - e^{-(10 + \sqrt{y})} & 0 \leq y \leq 100\\
     1 - e^{-(10 + \sqrt{y})} & y \gt 100
   \end{cases}
$